# compare the name of two files in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to hold all the objects that I need to make in a variable, and to make things easier, I am using a wildcard function to get all the .c files in the source directory, but that file also needs a corresponding .h file, so how I would check that such pairs of files exist?

```
SRCDIR := src 

C_SRCS    := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
C_HEADERS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h) 

# check if the basename of a c src matches with the basename of a header file
```

For example if the .c files were:

```
foo.c 
bar.c 
baz.c
```

and the .h files were:

```
foo.h
baz.h
thing.h
```

then the .o files should be

```
foo.o
baz.o
```

Comment: I don't quite understand.  You are already finding all the headers, with the `wildcard`.  Why do you want to "check that such a .h file exists"?

Comment: @MadScientist I updated the question to be more clear about what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: So you're saying that you don't want to even compile a source file unless a header file exists for it?  That's a very ... odd ... requirement.

Comment: @MadScientist maybe, but is it still possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to build any `.c` file that has a corresponding `.h` file but ignore any other `.c` file, you can do something like this:

```
ALL_HEADERS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
C_SRCS := $(wildcard $(ALL_HEADERS:%.h=%.c))
```

This will find all headers, then convert each one into a corresponding source file, then run `wildcard` on those which will result in only the ones that actually exist.